# How to configure Haskell / ghci module search path?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a first Application file,  Myapp.hs

I have created a module for parsing csv file , called Csvparser which is defined in a file Csvparser.hs.

Both files are in the same directory.

I don't understand how to import in Myapp.hs the Csvparser module

```
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List Data.Time Data.Either> :load C:\Test\Haskell\MyApp.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Test\Haskell\MyApp.hs, interpreted )

C:\Test\Haskell\MyApp.hs:5:1: error:
    Could not find module `Csvparser'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
5 | import Csvparser
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List Data.Time Data.Either>
```

The module can be loaded in standalone and works

```
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List Data.Time Data.Either> :load C:\Test\Haskell\Csvparser.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Csvparser        ( C:\Test\Haskell\Csvparser.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Csvparser Data.Maybe Data.List Data.Time Data.Either> import Csvparser
*Csvparser Data.Maybe Data.List Data.Time Data.Either Csvparser> :t Csvparser.parseCSV
Csvparser.parseCSV :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
*Csvparser Data.Maybe Data.List Data.Time Data.Either Csvparser>
```

Here is the failing syntax at line 5 of MyApp.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}


import Csvparser
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.ODBC
```

What can I do for making ghci/haskell understand that Csvparser module is to be found in the same directory of MyApp.hs ?

Comment: Try renaming the file to `Csvparser.hs`

Comment: @moondaisy : post edited,  actually there are named exactly identically;  case sensitive : module is Csvparser and file is Csvparser.h

Comment: If you run `ghci` from the folder that contains both files the import should work, but maybe you have a reason not to run it from there

Comment: You can also use `:cd C:\Test\Haskell` to change GHCi's directory to the one with your code. Note that this will also run your code in such directory (e.g. if your code creates a file, it will be created there).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to run `ghci` from a different folder that the one containing the file then do:

```
ghci -iC:\Test\Haskell\
```

`-i` sets the import search paths and then do:

```
:load C:\Test\Haskell\MyApp.hs
```

Or from inside the `ghci` console do:

```
:set -iC:\Test\Haskell\
```

If you want to see in which folder haskell is looking for the modules just call:

```
:show paths
```

It should print a list of paths under `module import search paths:`

All this isn't necessary if you run `ghci` from the folder that has your files, since by default Haskell will always look for the imports in the current folder.

**Don't leave a space between `-i` and the path**